# Mouse enter events for fontsize reduction in java

Tags: java, swing, events, fonts, jlabel

I have created a jlabel.now i need to increase its font size when mouse enter event occurs and decrease size back to normal when mouse leave event occurs.help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
aJLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent aE)
    {
        Font aFont = aJLabel.getFont();
        aJLabel.setFont(aFont.deriveFont((float) aFont.getSize() + 5));
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent aE)
    {
        Font aFont = aJLabel.getFont();
        aJLabel.setFont(aFont.deriveFont((float) aFont.getSize() - 5));
    }

});
```